# Checkmarx gives warning for HttpOnly cookies

Tags: c#, web-services, cookies, checkmarx

Checkmarx is flagging an error that looks like a false positive to me. Our application is a .NET web service, and we don't use cookies at all.

The error is:

> application configuration file, at line 1, does not define sensitive application cookies with the "httpOnly" flag, which could allow client-side scripts access to the session cookies.

What can be done to fix the issue? we don't want to add the `HttpCookie` attribute to config file as we don't use cookies.

Please suggest.